# Can we solve $2a(x^2-y^2)/(x-y)=b$ for $a$ without multiplying $b$ by $x-y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to know if its possible to pull $a$ out of the following equation without multiplying $b$ by $(x-y)$

$$ \frac{ 2a(x^2 - y^2)}{x - y} = b  $$

Its part of a more complex problem I'm stuck on.

Cheers

Comment: Notice $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for. Perhaps $$\frac{2(x^2-y^2)}{(x-y)}=\frac{b}{a}$$ is what you want?

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jakucha. What if the - was a + $$ \frac{ 2a(x^2 + y^2) }{ (x + y)} $$ Is it possible to pull a out without multiplying or dividing b

Comment: If by "pull $a$ out" you mean, "solve $2a(x^2+y^2)/(x+y)=b$ for $a$" then the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed, you have the identity
$$ x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y) $$
So, 
$$\dfrac{2a (x^2-y^2)}{x-y}=b \Leftrightarrow 2a(x+y)=b $$